# Gnuplot conditional plotting

Tags: conditional-statements, gnuplot

I need to use gnuplot to plot wind direction values (y) against time (x) in a 2D plot using lines and points. This works fine if successive values are close together. If the values are eg separated by 250 degrees then I need to have a condition that checks the previous y value and does not draw a line joining the two points. This condition occurs when the wind dir is in the 280 degrees to 20 degrees sector and the plots are messy eg a north wind. AS the data is time dependent I cannot use polar plots except at a specific point in time. I need to show change in direction over time.

Basically the problem is:

plot y against x ; when (y2-y1)>= 180 then break/erase line joining successive points
Can anyone give me an example of how to do this?

A sample from the data file is:

```
2014-06-16 16:00:00 0.000 990.081 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.002 0.001 11.868 308 002.54 292 004.46 00 
2014-06-16 16:10:00 0.000 990.047 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.002 0.001 11.870 303 001.57 300 002.48 00 
2014-06-16 16:20:00 0.000 990.014 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.002 0.001 11.961 334 001.04 314 002.07 00 
2014-06-16 16:30:00 0.000 990.014 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.002 0.001 11.818 005 001.18 020 002.14 00 
2014-06-16 16:40:00 0.000 990.014 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.002 0.001 11.725 332 001.14 337 002.26 00
```

and I want to plot column 12 vs time.

Comment: Why not you filter lines using awk utility and keep only required lines to be given as input to gnuplot

Comment: Thanks Stauz - I need to retain all values, no data can be omitted. Its just the lines connecting points that are the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert a filtering condition in the `using` statement and use a value of `1/0` if the condition is not fullfilled. In that case this point is not connect to others:

```
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
set xdata time
unset key

y1 = y2 = 0
plot 'data.dat' using 1:(y1 = y2, y2 = $12, ($0 == 0 || y2 - y1 < 180) ? $12 : 1/0) with lines,\
     'data.dat' using 1:12 with points
```

With your data sample and gnuplot version 4.6.5 I get the plot:

[image]

Unfortunately, with this approach you cannot categorize lines, but only points and also the line following the `1/0` point aren't drawn.

A better approach would be to use `awk` to insert an empty line when a jump occurs. In a 2D-plot points from different data blocks (separated by a single new line) aren't connected:

```
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
set xdata time
unset key

plot '< awk ''{y1 = y2; y2 = $12; if (NR > 1 && y2 - y1 >= 180) printf("\n"); print}'' data.dat' using 1:12 with linespoints
```

Comment: Thank you Cristoph - when I try your suggestion I get 'undefined variable: y2'...

Comment: Data sample : 2014-06-16 00:10:00 0.000 990.147 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.002 0.001 11.479 248 004.16 257 004.81 00 
2014-06-16 00:20:00 0.000 990.147 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.002 0.001 11.509 247 004.04 241 005.06 00 
2014-06-16 00:30:00 0.000 990.180 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.002 0.001 11.506 258 004.86 259 006.14 00 
2014-06-16 00:40:00 0.000 990.147 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.002 0.001 11.505 253 003.67 256 005.16 00 
2014-06-16 00:50:00 0.000 990.081 0.001 0.001 0.000 0.001 0.002 0.001 11.489 243 003.64 254 004.41 00 
I am plotting column 12 vs time

Comment: Here is more data with y (Column 12) crossing 360 degrees :2014-06-16 16:00:00 0.000 990.081 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.002 0.001 11.868 308 002.54 292 004.46 00 
2014-06-16 16:10:00 0.000 990.047 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.002 0.001 11.870 303 001.57 300 002.48 00 
2014-06-16 16:20:00 0.000 990.014 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.002 0.001 11.961 334 001.04 314 002.07 00 
2014-06-16 16:30:00 0.000 990.014 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.002 0.001 11.818 005 001.18 020 002.14 00 
2014-06-16 16:40:00 0.000 990.014 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.002 0.001 11.725 332 001.14 337 002.26 00

Comment: Ok, see my edit. I think the `awk` variant should work best. I included the data samples in your question. If you do this by yourself, just do copy&paste, mark the data and press Ctrl+K to format it properly.

Comment: I am trying awk as you suggested - input : plot  "<awk  '{y1 = y2; y2 = $12; if (NR > 1 && y2 - y1 >= 180) printf("\n"); print}" '/Desktop/plotdata.txt' with linespoints ......This gives me err msg as follows : plot  "<awk  '{y1 = y2; y2 = $12; if (NR > 1 && y2 - y1 >= 180) printf("\n"); print}" '/Desktop/plotdata.txt' with linespoints
                                                                                 ^
         invalid character \

(in       printf("\n");)

Comment: Please copy&paste the plot command and replace only the file name. You must care about the different quotation marks in different places. In my command they are correct.

Comment: Further to your suggestion - here is my input line - gnuplot is now asking for format specifiers.gnuplot> plot '< awk ''{y1 = y2; y2 = $12; if (NR > 1 && y2 - y1 >= 180) printf("\n"); print}' using 1:12 '/Desktop/plotdata.txt ' '%lf' with linespoints
                                                                                                                                                    ^
         format must have 1-7 conversions of type double (%lf)

Comment: Please use backticks to format the comments properly. Yes, the command was missing the `using` statement, but you added the file name in the wrong place. Only replace `data.dat` with `/Desktop/plotdata.txt`: `plot '< awk ''{y1 = y2; y2 = $12; if (NR > 1 && y2 - y1 >= 180) printf("\n"); print}'' /Desktop/plotdata.txt' using 1:12 with linespoints`.

Comment: Here are the intial format settings : these should be correct.      gnuplot> show format

        tic format is:
          x-axis: "             %d/%m-%H:%M"
          y-axis: "% g"
          x2-axis: "% g"
          y2-axis: "% g"
          z-axis: "% g"
          cb-axis: "% g"
          r-axis: "% g"

gnuplot> plot '< awk ''{y1 = y2; y2 = $12; if (NR > 1 && y2 - y1 >= 180) printf("\n"); print}' using 1:12 '/Desktop/plotdata.txt ' with linespoints

Comment: Argh, why do you refuse to copy&paste the correct command I posted in my previous comment?

Comment: Apologies - I had an initial condition that was incorrect - took a while to find it. Code works - just need to tweak it a bit. Many thanks for your help Cristoph

Answer (score 1):

In order to break the joining lines two conditional statements must be fulfilled and BOTH must include the newline statement printf("\n"):

plot '< awk ''{y1 = y2; y2 = $12; if (NR > 1 && y2 - y1 >= 180) printf("\n") ; if (NR > 1 && y2 -y1 <= 0) printf("\n"); print}'' /Desktop/plotdata.txt' using 1:12 with linespoints

Comment: To have it a bit shorter, you can use the condition `if (NR > 1 && (y2-y1 >= 180 || y2-y1 <= 0)) printf("\n")` :)

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need for awk. You can simply "interrupt" the lines by using variable color for the line. For gnuplot<5.0.0 you can use `0xffffff`=white (or whatever your background color is) as linecolor and the line will hardly be visible. For gnuplot>=5.0.0 you can use any transparent color, e.g. `0xff123456`, i.e. the line is really invisible.

**Data:** `SO24425910.dat`

```
2014-06-16 16:00:00   330
2014-06-16 16:10:00   320
2014-06-16 16:20:00   310
2014-06-16 16:30:00   325
2014-06-16 16:40:00   090
2014-06-16 16:50:00   060
2014-06-16 17:00:00   070
2014-06-16 17:10:00   280
2014-06-16 17:20:00   290
2014-06-16 17:30:00   300
```

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=4.4.0, March 2010)

```
### conditional interruption of line
reset

FILE = "SO24425910.dat"

set key noautotitle
set yrange[0:360]
set ytics 90
set grid x
set grid y
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
set format x "%H:%M"

set multiplot layout 2,1

    plot y1=NaN FILE u 1:(y0=y1,y1=$3):(abs(y1-y0)>=180?0xffffff:0xff0000) w l lc rgb var

    plot y1=NaN FILE u 1:(y0=y1,y1=$3):(abs(y1-y0)>=180?0xffffff:0xff0000) w l lc rgb var, \
                  '' u 1:3 w p pt 7 lc rgb "red"

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]